# Octopus deploy custom dashboad (how to see pending releases)

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

Are there any solutions available for a custom octopus dashboard? The issue I'm having is that the default dashboard does not show pending releases. If you have a lot of projects which are manually deployed to a DEV or STAGING environment there doesn't seem to be an easy way to see which projects have pending releases in the octopus dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Octopus Deploy exposes a [REST API](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Octopus+REST+API), so you could create your own custom dashboard.